# Does Python have a function which computes multinomial coefficients?

Tags: python, scipy, combinatorics

I was looking for a Python library function which computes [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients).

I could not find any such function in any of the standard libraries. 
For binomial coefficients (of which multinomial coefficients are a generalization) there is [scipy.special.binom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.binom.html) and also [scipy.misc.comb](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.comb.html). Also, [numpy.random.multinomial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html) draws samples from a multinomial distribution, and [sympy.ntheory.multinomial.multinomial_coefficients](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/ntheory/multinomial.html) returns a dictionary related to multinomial coefficients.

However, I could *not* find a multinomial coefficients function proper, which given *a,b,...,z* returns *(a+b+...+z)!/(a! b! ... z!).* Did I miss it? Is there a good reason there is none available?

I would be happy to contribute an efficient implementation to SciPy say. (I would have to figure out how to contribute, as I have never done this).

For background, they do come up when expanding *(a+b+...+z)^n.* Also, they count the ways of depositing *a+b+...+z* distinct objects into distinct bins such that the first bin contains *a* objects, etc. I need them occasionally for a Project Euler problem.

BTW, other languages do offer this function: [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Multinomial.html), [MATLAB](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6786-multcoef), [Maple](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6786-multcoef).

Comment: As this is my first question I would be curious to learn why the question is down-voted. My searching did not yield an answer to my question. Also, I have provided some background. Thanks in advance for any clarifications.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* More information: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please help me understand, how would such a specific technical question attract opinionated answers? Either the function is available, but maybe well hidden or under an unusual name, or there is a good reason why the library designers have chosen to not implement it, or it is simply a gap (which I would be glad to fill). Note that I am *not* asking for a recommendation.

Comment: The question such as this is off-topic in SO. We are programmers and we are human, we choose the libraries for a particular reason, because we feel comfortable, that is, there may be n libraries and any of us will like some for some reason is objective or not. So for that reason SO considers it to be off topic. I recommend you change your question and assume that it does not exist, maybe it exists, and shows what you have tried, and surely if there is already the solution someone in the community will respond with the name of the function or else propose some alternative.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now. I think you have misunderstood my question (probably because it is badly worded). The 4 examples I give are all NOT the function I am looking for, they are only loosely related to it. I listed them to show that I have done some work. I will make the question clearer.

Comment: If you only need to calculate the multinomial coefficient `(n1, n2, ... nk )!` why not just use a self defined function instead of searching for a whole library?

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Still, as this is such a relatively basic function it would seem natural to me to have it in Python. It is available in Mathematica snd in MATLAB, for example. As I wrote, I would be happy to contribute my code, but would love to hear any good reasons why I (or anyboby) should not.

Comment: @ReinerMartin From the experience I have I have observed that the questions where the author shows and explains what he has tried are the ones that are usually answered.

Comment: Which is exactly what I did, that is why I am confused.

Comment: Why would anything that can be implemented which just uses `sum`, `map` and`math.factorial` be part of the language?

Comment: @Nick A: Because that is very inefficient in general, for the same reason binomial coefficients are not implemented this way.

Comment: @Reiner then the real question is why do you need it to be that efficient

Comment: @Nick A: Because you will need that if you do Project Euler, for example. (https://projecteuler.net/profile/reinermartin.png)

Comment: @Reiner can you give an example of such a question?

Comment: Yes, it shows up in https://projecteuler.net/problem=369, which I am just working on (my 401st).

Comment: @ReinerMartin (belated) welcome to StackOverflow, and apologies for our pathetic social skills.  Thanks for being a good sport.

Comment: Thanks Don! BTW, I've added your good suggestion to my answer

Comment: You might be interested in the Q&A and comments on a 'slow' decrementer that avoids multiplications. See [What is the math behind this Python program generating multinomial coefficients?] (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3533038/432081).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To partially answer my own question, here is my simple and fairly efficient implementation of the multinomial function:

```
def multinomial(lst):
    res, i = 1, 1
    for a in lst:
        for j in range(1,a+1):
            res *= i
            res //= j
            i += 1
    return res
```

It seems from the comments so far that no efficient implementation of the function exists in any of the standard libraries.

*Update (January 2020).* As Don Hatch has pointed out in the comments, this can be further improved by looking for the largest argument (especially for the case that it dominates all others):

```
def multinomial(lst):
    res, i = 1, sum(lst)
    i0 = lst.index(max(lst))
    for a in lst[:i0] + lst[i0+1:]:
        for j in range(1,a+1):
            res *= i
            res //= j
            i -= 1
    return res
```

Comment: In my experience it is faster to use `sum()` and `math.factorial()`  to calculate the formula.

Comment: It depends of course what you are trying to do. You won't solve any (3-digit) Project Euler problems with that approach

Comment: Hi Reiner, I accidentally upvoted your answer before I realized it's actually not very good. `multinomial([10**7,2])` takes 0.8s.  `multinomial([10**8,2])` takes 8s. `multinomial([10**9,2])` crashes my machine (python2) or takes 80s (python3).  All of these could be instant.

Comment: You could fix it pretty easily, though.  One way would be the following: replace the first two lines in your function with `res = 1`; `i = sum(lst)`; `index_of_max = lst.index(max(lst))`; `for a in lst[:index_of_max] + lst[index_of_max+1:]:`,  and then replace the `i+=1` with `i-=1`.

Comment: In fact, the trivial `multinomial([10**8,1])` and even more trivial `multinomial([10**8,0])` also demonstrate the problem with your code.

Comment: @DonHatch If execution time is mission critical you can use a 'thin' table of binomial coefficients stored in memory; see [How do I compute multinomials efficiently?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3535472/432081) \math.stackexchange

Answer (score 10):

No, there is not a built-in multinomial library or function in Python.

Anyway this time math could help you. In fact a simple method for calculating the multinomial

[image]

keeping an eye on the performance is to rewrite it by using the characterization of the multinomial coefficient as a product of binomial coefficients:

[image]

where of course

[image]

Thanks to [`scipy.special.binom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.binom.html) and the magic of recursion you can solve the problem like this:

```
from scipy.special import binom

def multinomial(params):
    if len(params) == 1:
        return 1
    return binom(sum(params), params[-1]) * multinomial(params[:-1])
```

where `params = [n1, n2, ..., nk]`.

**Note:** Splitting the multinomial as a product of binomial is also good to prevent overflow in general.

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially how I have done it (unwrapping the recursion into loops for performance). However, this was not my question; rather: would it be a good idea to include it into SciPy say (if it is not already, which it seems not to be), as it is present in a few other languages? Believe me, I don't need a lecture in math.

Comment: That's really a question to ask the `scipy` maintainers.

Comment: OK, good point, will do. This was probably the wrong audience. Thanks.

Comment: That said, I wasn't sure whether there is another library besides SciPy where it is included.

Comment: Here an update, over a year later. For my problem-solving programming (say for Project Euler) I have in the meantime completely switched to Julia, which is in my opinion much better suited for stuff like this. As an aside, the multinomial function is contained in Julia's Combinatorics library, as you would expect.

Comment: The `binom` function returns floating point number that may not be correct; see Warren Weckesser's answer.

Comment: @ReinerMartin You say "this is essentially how I have done it".  No, it isn't; you  might want to take a closer look :-)  Marco's answer computes `multinomial([10**9,2])` instantly, as it should; yours doesn't.  (However, Marco's  gives the answer as double-precision floating point number, which is only an approximation to the correct answer; in fact, it's off by 1.  I have no idea how scipy.special.binom is implemented, but it's clearly not the right tool for this job.)

Comment: @Marco You say "Note: Splitting the multinomial as a product of binomial is also good to prevent overflow in general."  Are you sure?  It certainly doesn't help the naive implementation, since the largest number that occurs in the calculation is still `(n1+n2+...+nk)!`.   If you mean something else by the statement, and you think it's meaningful, could you clarify?

Comment: @jarno I didn't understand your comment, in a couple of ways, at first.  To clarify, for others: (1) an example where this returns an incorrect answer is `multinomial([10**9,2])` which returns 5.000000015e+17; the correct answer is 500000001500000001. But at least it's fast :-)   (2) You mention Warren Weckesser's answer; at first I thought you were referring to the first program given in that answer (which isn't a very good solution, as ReinerMartin explained).  But I see now that you were referring to the second program in that answer, which is an improvement to the answer here, as you said.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote *"`sympy.ntheory.multinomial.multinomial_coefficients` returns a dictionary related to multinomial coefficients"*, but it is not clear from that comment if you know how to extract the specific coefficients from that dictionary.  Using the notation from the wikipedia link, the SymPy function gives you *all* the multinomial coefficients for the given *m* and *n*.  If you only want a specific coefficient, just pull it out of the dictionary:

```
In [39]: from sympy import ntheory

In [40]: def sympy_multinomial(params):
    ...:     m = len(params)
    ...:     n = sum(params)
    ...:     return ntheory.multinomial_coefficients(m, n)[tuple(params)]
    ...: 

In [41]: sympy_multinomial([1, 2, 3])
Out[41]: 60

In [42]: sympy_multinomial([10, 20, 30])
Out[42]: 3553261127084984957001360
```

Busy Beaver gave an answer written in terms of `scipy.special.binom`. A potential problem with that implementation is that `binom(n, k)` returns a floating point value.  If the coefficient is large enough, it will not be exact, so it would probably not help you with a Project Euler problem.  Instead of `binom`, you can use [`scipy.special.comb`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.comb.html), with the argument `exact=True`.  This is Busy Beaver's function, modified to use `comb`:

```
In [46]: from scipy.special import comb

In [47]: def scipy_multinomial(params):
    ...:     if len(params) == 1:
    ...:         return 1
    ...:     coeff = (comb(sum(params), params[-1], exact=True) *
    ...:              scipy_multinomial(params[:-1]))
    ...:     return coeff
    ...: 

In [48]: scipy_multinomial([1, 2, 3])
Out[48]: 60

In [49]: scipy_multinomial([10, 20, 30])
Out[49]: 3553261127084984957001360
```

Comment: Thanks, I had indeed not looked into how to get specific coefficients from that dictionary. It struck me as incredible wasteful to generate a full dictionary when I only want to compute a single value, and so I did a quick timing for some larger inputs. sympy_multinomial([123,134,145]) for example takes over 1000 times as long as my own simple function.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches, one using factorials, one using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

### Using factorials

You can define a function to return multinomial coefficients in a single line using vectorised code (instead of `for`-loops) as follows:

```py
from scipy.special import factorial

def multinomial_coeff(c):
    return factorial(c.sum()) / factorial(c).prod()
```

(Where `c` is an `np.ndarray` containing the number of counts for each different object). Usage example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> coeffs = np.array([2, 3, 4])
>>> multinomial_coeff(coeffs)
1260.0
```

In some cases this might be slower because you will be computing certain factorial expressions multiple times, in other cases this might be faster because I believe that numpy naturally parallelises vectorised code. Also this reduces the required number of lines in your program and is arguably more readable. If someone has the time to run speed tests on these different options then I'd be interested to see the results.

### Using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

In fact the **logarithm** of the multinomial coefficient is much **faster** to compute (based on [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)) and allows computation of much larger coefficients:

```py
from scipy.special import gammaln

def log_multinomial_coeff(c):
    return gammaln(c.sum()+1) - gammaln(c+1).sum()
```

Usage example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> coeffs = np.array([2, 3, 4])
>>> np.exp(log_multinomial_coeff(coeffs))
1259.999999999999
```

Comment: In fact the logarithm of the multinomial coefficient is faster to compute (based on the Stirling approximation) and allows computation of much larger coefficients:

`from scipy.special import gammaln`
`def log_multinomial_coeff(c): return gammaln(c.sum()+1) - gammaln(c+1).sum()`

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the previous comment

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Python 3.8`,

- since the standard library now includes the [`math.comb`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html?highlight=comb#math.comb) function (binomial coefficient)
- and since the multinomial coefficient can be computed as a [product of binomial coefficients](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/0618a64f7b9624fd8ae0df67100096d16cf016c2)

we can implement it without external libraries:

```
import math

def multinomial(*params):
  return math.prod(math.comb(sum(params[:i]), x) for i, x in enumerate(params, 1))

multinomial(10, 20, 30) # 3553261127084984957001360
```

Comment: If performance is an issue, this is unfortunately somewhat inefficient, since a lot of terms cancel out which this method takes no advantage of.

Answer (score 1):

Your own answer (the accepted one) is quite good, and is especially simple. However, it does have one significant inefficiency: your outer loop `for a in lst` is executed one more time than is necessary. In the first pass through that loop, the values of `i` and `j` are always identical, so the multiplications and divisions do nothing. In your example `multinomial([123, 134, 145])`, there are `123` unneeded multiplications and divisions, adding time to the code.

I suggest finding the maximum value in the parameters and removing it, so those unneeded operations are not done. That adds complexity to the code but reduces the execution time, especially for short lists of large numbers. My code below executes `multcoeff(123, 134, 145)` in `111` microseconds, while your code takes `141` microseconds. That is not a large increase, but that could matter. So here is my code. This also takes individual values as parameters rather than a list, so that is another difference from your code.

```
def multcoeff(*args):
    """Return the multinomial coefficient
    (n1 + n2 + ...)! / n1! / n2! / ..."""
    if not args:  # no parameters
        return 1
    # Find and store the index of the largest parameter so we can skip
    #   it (for efficiency)
    skipndx = args.index(max(args))
    newargs = args[:skipndx] + args[skipndx + 1:]

    result = 1
    num = args[skipndx] + 1  # a factor in the numerator
    for n in newargs:
        for den in range(1, n + 1):  # a factor in the denominator
            result = result * num // den
            num += 1
    return result
```