# How to arrange 5 M, 5 S and 5 T such that M and T are not adjacent and string starts with M and ends with T

Tags: math, permutation

**Problem** : 5 monkeys, 5 snakes and 5 tigers are standing in a line in a grocery store, with animals of the same species being indistinguishable. A monkey stands in the front of the line, and a tiger stands at the end of the line. Unfortunately, tigers and monkeys are sworn enemies, so monkeys and tigers cannot stand in adjacent places in line. Compute the number of possible arrangements of the line.

Solving this problem by hand is daunting. I want to write a program to output the possible arrangements and also count the total arrangements. My first thought was to use a brute force.  Monkeys, snakes, and tigers can be represented by the letters M, S, and T respectively. With 1 M at start of string and 1 T at the end, there are 13!/(4!4!5!) = 90,090 possibilities. I would then remove arrangements that do not satisfy the second condition about adjacency.

My second thought was to first compute the number of arrangements where M and T are adjacent and then subtract this number from 90,090. I am new to programming so I am not sure how to do this.

Is there a better way to approach these types of problems? Any hints?
Thank you.

Comment: A better way: Find a source of infinite bananas and infinite monkeys.

Comment: *"Is there a better way to approach these types of problems? Any hints? Thank you."* Yes! The ["stars and bars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) approach comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR: python solution using sympy

```py
import sympy # sympy.ntheory.multinomial_coefficients
import math  # math.comb

def count_monkeytigers(n_monkeys, n_snakes, n_tigers):
  return sum(
    m * math.comb(n_monkeys - 1, mb_minus1) * math.comb(n_tigers - 1, tb_minus1)
    for (mb_minus1, eb, tb_minus1), m in
      sympy.ntheory.multinomial_coefficients(3, n_snakes-1).items()
  )
```

## Explanation

We already know that there is an `M` at the beginning, a `T` at the end, and five `S` in the string:

```
  M??  S  ??  S  ??  S  ??  S  ??  S  ??T
```

Since `M` and `T` cannot be adjacent, and the only way to separate them is with an `S`, you can think of the `S` as separators; the five `S` are cutting the string into 6 "bins". Every bin can either be empty, or contain one or more M, or contain one or more T. Furthermore, the first bin contains at least an M, and the last bin contains at least a T.

To count all permutations of the string, we can do the following:

- Loop over the triplets `(monkey_bins, empty_bins, tiger_bins)` deciding how many bins have monkeys, are empty, or have tigers;
- For the loop, we can use bounds `1 <= monkey_bins <= 5`; `0 <= empty_bins <= 5 - monkey_bins`; `tiger_bins = 6 - monkey_bins - empty_bins`;
- Count the number `m` of ways to choose `monkey_bins` bins, `empty_bins` bins and `tiger_bins` bins among 6 bins ([Multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients));
- Count the number `monkey_partitions` of ways to place `n_monkeys` 'M' into `monkey_bins` bins with at least one M per bin ([Stars and bars theorem 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one));
- Count the number `tiger_partitions` of ways to place `n_tigers` 'T' into `tiger_bins` bins with at least one T per bin ([Stars and bars theorem 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one);
- Add `m * monkey_partitions * tiger_partitions` to the count.

### Python code with loops

```py
import math

def multinomial(*params):
  return math.prod(math.comb(sum(params[:i]), x) for i, x in enumerate(params, 1))

def count_monkeytigers(n_monkeys, n_snakes, n_tigers):
  result = 0
  for monkey_bins in range(1, n_snakes + 1):
    for empty_bins in range(0, n_snakes + 1 - monkey_bins):
      tiger_bins = n_snakes + 1 - monkey_bins - empty_bins
      m = multinomial(monkey_bins - 1, empty_bins, tiger_bins - 1) # nb permutations of the 3 types of bins
      monkey_partitions = math.comb(n_monkeys - 1, monkey_bins - 1)
      tiger_partitions = math.comb(n_tigers - 1, tiger_bins - 1)
      result += m * monkey_partitions * tiger_partitions
  return result

print(count_monkeytigers(5, 5, 5))
# 1251

print(count_monkeytigers(2,2,2))
# 3
# = len(['MMSSTT', 'MSMSTT', 'MMSTST'])
```

The code for `multinomial` comes from this question:

- [Does python have a function which computes multinomial coefficients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374185/does-python-have-a-function-which-computes-multinomial-coefficients)

Note that we're only using a "trinomial" coefficient here, so you can replace function `multinomial` with this simpler function if you want:

```py
def trinomial(k1,k2,k3):
  return math.comb(k1+k2+k3, k1) * math.comb(k2+k3, k2)
```

### Python code using `sympy`

In the previous python code, we're manually looping over the possible triplets (monkey_bins, empty_bins, tiger_bins) and using the corresponding binomial coefficients. As it turns out,  `sympy.ntheory.multinomial_coefficients(m, n)` returns a dictionary that contains specifically those triplets as keys and the corresponding multinomial coefficients as values!
We can use that to shorten our code:

```py
import sympy # sympy.ntheory.multinomial_coefficients
import math  # math.comb

def count_monkeytigers(n_monkeys, n_snakes, n_tigers):
  return sum(
    m * math.comb(n_monkeys - 1, mb_minus1) * math.comb(n_tigers - 1, tb_minus1)
    for (mb_minus1, eb, tb_minus1), m in
      sympy.ntheory.multinomial_coefficients(3, n_snakes-1).items()
  )

print(count_monkeytigers(5, 5, 5))
# 1251

print(count_monkeytigers(2,2,2))
# 3
# = len(['MMSSTT', 'MSMSTT', 'MMSTST'])
```

Note that the dictionary `multinomial_coefficients(3, n)` contains all triplets of nonnegative numbers summing to `n`, including those where the middle-element `empty_bins` is equal to `n`, and the other two elements are 0. But we want at least one bin with monkeys, and at least one bin with tigers; hence I called the triplet `(mb_minus1, eb, tb_minus1)` rather than `(mb, eb, tb)`, and accordingly I used `n_snakes-1` rather than `n_snakes+1` as the sum of the triplet.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing code directly , Just solve the question on paper upto the factorial notations , then you can easily find factorial in Code

At first , fix 1 monkey at front and 1 tiger at end .

Then try to fix remaining tigers , then fix snakes in adjancent of tigers , Atleast one snake must be in adjacent of a tiger and then fix monkeys in adjacent of snakes

Comment: Suppose I made 2 groups of 2 tigers, 2 groups of 2 snakes, and 1 snake as follows :        M SS TT SS TT S T. How to I find the number of ways to place the remaining 4 monkeys with coding? I am having trouble with the coding part. I can only code brute force.

Comment: Monkey can only be placed adjacent to snake only